# How to create asset from existing blob in the associated blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I need to upload files from local system to azure media services. I have uploaded the content from client machine to AMS using HTML5 uploader(browser chunk upload). reference from,
http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-
storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript.

Now I need to move the uploaded file from blob storage to Azure Media Services as asset and publish. How to achieve this. can anyone provide example for this process.

Answer (score 1):

From this link: [`Copying an Existing Blob into a Media Services Asset v2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-copying-existing-blob)

⚠️ **Media Service API v2 (obsolete, v2 will be retired on 29 February 2024)**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Creates a new asset and copies blobs from the specifed storage account.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mediaBlobContainer">The specified blob container.</param>
    /// <returns>The new asset.</returns>
    static public IAsset CreateAssetFromExistingBlobs(CloudBlobContainer mediaBlobContainer)
    {
        // Create a new asset. 
        IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create("CopyBlob_" + Guid.NewGuid(), AssetCreationOptions.None);

        IAccessPolicy writePolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("writePolicy", TimeSpan.FromHours(24), AccessPermissions.Write);
        ILocator destinationLocator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, writePolicy);

        CloudBlobClient destBlobStorage = _destinationStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Get the asset container URI and Blob copy from mediaContainer to assetContainer. 
        string destinationContainerName = (new Uri(destinationLocator.Path)).Segments[1];

        CloudBlobContainer assetContainer = destBlobStorage.GetContainerReference(destinationContainerName);

        if (assetContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            assetContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });
        }

        var blobList = mediaBlobContainer.ListBlobs();
        foreach (var sourceBlob in blobList)
        {
            var assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create((sourceBlob as ICloudBlob).Name);
            CopyBlob(sourceBlob as ICloudBlob, assetContainer);
            assetFile.ContentFileSize = (sourceBlob as ICloudBlob).Properties.Length;
            assetFile.Update();
        }

        destinationLocator.Delete();
        writePolicy.Delete();

        // Since we copied a set of Smooth Streaming files, 
        // set the .ism file to be the primary file. 
        SetISMFileAsPrimary(asset);

        return asset;
    }
```

Comment: Hi gaurav, First of all thanks for your HTML5 upload code. The above code will fetch all item and copy to destination storage. Actually I want to copy or move file after your HTML5 upload. Once chunks get uploaded to storage container, i want to move that blob to media server associated asset container. Here the media server associated container is the source container.

Comment: In the example above, blobs are copied from another container to an asset container. I thought this is what you want, right? Or may be I am not understanding your question.

Comment: After upload file to blob storage with your code, it should be moved to asset container. Moreover if videos have same name means, will it create different asset ID in asset right ?

Comment: and you want to do all through client side JS?

Comment: Not necessary. I created SAS in server side call (AJAX) for upload. either sever side or client side not prob. your code uploaded content to blob storage, then how to move it to asset container, then i have to do encoding and encryption and will publish. if i moved to asset container and get asset means, i will do other things..

Comment: So here's what you could do. Essentially once the upload completes, you get the blob URL. You can pass this URL to server side code which knows about your asset container. Then essentially you will copy this blob to asset container. Once the blob is copied, you would just need to create an object of type `AssetFile` (last 4 lines of code above minus the code to copy the blobs). It's been a while that I worked with Media Service so I may be wrong here. Please give it a try and share your findings.

Comment: yeah i will try and let you know, gaurav.

Comment: Hi gaurav, thanks for your help. I copied blob from storage container to asset container. I will try to implement this in my application.